# Setting a div to have the dimensions of an A4 sheet of paper works in portrait, but not landscape

Tags: css, mpdf

I am making a HTML document to convert to PDF using the mPDF tool.

To that affect I have made a wrapping div that has the dimensions of a piece of A4 paper:

```
.wrapper{
    height:210mm;
    width:297mm;
    page-break-after:always;
}
```

This works fine. It fits and prints perfectly on an A4.

But when I swap the values to make it landscape:

```
.wrapper{
    height:297mm;
    width:210mm;
    page-break-after:always;
}
```

The page overlaps and takes up 2 pages.

Would anyone know why this is?